# Configuration of the all field elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I have a problem with the ES _all field for example this doc:

```
field_1: "ar"
field_2: "gus"
```

When i do the query "ar gus" with _all, this matches, I understand why

```
_all = "ar gus"
```

but is there any way to this query not match, like adding some offset to the strings or a delimiter?

```
_all = "ar (space)(space) or some other gus"
```

I have search a lot but i haven't found anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want your document to match "ar gus" but not "ar  gus" you need to use a [match_phrase query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) (check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/slop.html) too) and configure the `slop` attribute in the search query.

Just to be sure, you can disable the `_all` field if it bothers you ([here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html), disabled by default in ES 6.X).